# Java: Use streams to join 2D string[][] array with 2 different delimiters

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-stream

I've created a database schema as a 2D array of strings. I'd like to combine the whole thing into a format like

```
"id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ssl_support BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
supported_request_formats VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
... "
```

(newlines added for clarity)

However, with the code that I have below, Eclipse underlines the entire chunk starting with `Arrays.stream` in red and labels it with the error

`Cannot invoke collect(Collector<CharSequence,capture#5-of ?,String>) on the primitive type void`.

I don't understand this error because the inner collect() should be returning a `String`, not `primitive type void`.

```
  private static final String[][] COLUMN_DATA = {
    {"id",                                              "INT",          "AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY" },
    { "ssl_support",                                    "BOOLEAN",      "NOT NULL" },
    { "supported_request_formats",                      "VARCHAR(7)",   "NOT NULL" },
    // ...
  };

  @Override
  public String getCreationString() {

    return "CREATE TABLE apis ("
        + Arrays.stream(COLUMN_DATA)
            .forEach(col -> Arrays.stream(col)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
        + ")";

    /*
     * Expected output:
     * 
     *  "CREATE TABLE apis (
     *    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     *    ssl_support BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
     *    supported_request_formats VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
     *    ...
     *  )"
     */
  }
```

Comment: You're trying to call `collect` on the result of `foreach`, but `foreach` doesn't ___return___ something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [the `forEach` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)), that is a terminal operation on the stream.  It performs an action on each element in the stream, but it doesn't return anything -- not another `Stream`, not anything generated by your lambda expression -- nothing.

Instead, you should transform each internal array into the string that you want, keeping it in the stream to be collected later.  Use [the `map` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)).

```
return "CREATE TABLE apis ("
            + Arrays.stream(COLUMN_DATA)
            .map(col -> Arrays.stream(col)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
                    )
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
            + ")";
```

Comment: Or just `.map(col -> String.join(" ", col))`. Whereas for the outer operation, I’d use `.collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "CREATE TABLE apis (", ")"))` instead of performing another string concatenation after the Stream operation.

Answer (score 1):

The `.forEach()` is a terminate operation.

---

You need

```
Arrays.stream(COLUMN_DATA)
      .map(col -> Arrays.stream(col).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```